# How to Import FieldValue from firebase-admin using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

**Is it possible to import FieldValue from firebase-admin npm using this style?**

```
import { FieldValue } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';
```

By default my visual studio Code imports in this way:

```
import {FieldValue} from '@google-cloud/firestore';
```

but in this way, I have to add a new package only to import FieldValue ...

**Is there any way to import it from firebase-admin using Typescript?**

Answer (score 17):

If you import like this:

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin'
```

You can find it like this:

```
firestore.FieldValue
```

as it's re-exported from @google-cloud/firstore as part of its exported `admin.firestore` namespace.

Comment: What if you just want fieldvalue and you don't want to import the entirety of firestore

Answer (score 4):

**Note: I have tried the above solution and that did not work.**

I have been searching for this for like a whole day and found the solution from one of the firebase NodeJS snippets repositories. I know it is not in typescript so just change the import accordingly.

```
// for the import part
const {getFirestore, FieldValue} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");
// for typescript it might be
// import {FieldValue} from 'firebase-admin/firestore';

// also, getFirestore is another import I needed and you might not so change accordingly

// for the update
await admin
 .firestore()
 .collection("Posts").doc(docId).update({
   postImages: FieldValue.arrayUnion(signedUrl),
 }).then((_) => {
    functions.logger.log("Updated the image link successfully");
 });
```

Comment: This works, thanks. By the way 2nd gen Node.js cloud funcs are much more mess with imports imho.